# Automatically resize a div which contains other two div

Tags: html, css

```css
@media only screen and (min-width: 900px) {
  .map_left {
    display: inline; 
    float:left; 
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 3px solid green;
  }

  .map_right { 
    display: inline; 
    float:right;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 3px solid blue;
  }
}
```

Why is the first div(which contains the other two div) does not resize itself? I don't want to set width and height using pixel, I would like to make it resize by itself, is it possible?

[image]

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="prova.css"/> 
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <center><div style="border: 3px solid">
      <div class="map_left" width="90%"></div>
      <div  class="map_right" width="90%"></div>
    </div></center>
  </body>
```

Comment: where is your css??!! and, probably because you put those two div's inside some div, but those two divs, suppose, have `float` style... of course, it's just guessing until you provide us css... what is `map_left` and `map_right` styles??

Answer (score 0):

Because you set `witdth="1000px"`, put `xxx%` or nothing (default is 100%)

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>

  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="prova.css"/> 

  <title></title>
 </head>

 <body>
   

<center><div style="border: 3px solid;width:100%">


<div class="map_left" width="90%">

</div>

<div  class="map_right" width="90%">

</div>


</div></center>



</body>
```